# SQL - How create a select that makes search possible

Tags: sql

I was trying to create a search where you could search by typing some part of the name. But when the search input is empty it shows everyone in the table.
I tried to write the SQL to select * when the search input is = to " "(empty) and to select * that has at least part of the sentence when the search as 1 character or more, but everytime if i write something it works, but when the search input is empty any row is selected. My code is:

```
SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE [nome] LIKE '%@search%'
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: The question is not clear.  What is the desired result if the input parameter is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using SQL Server:

```
WHERE [nome] LIKE '%' + coalesce(@search, '') + '%'
```

However, you might consider full text search using `contains()`.

EDIT:

Ooops, I thought you *wanted* the query to return everything when the search string is empty.  How about:

```
WHERE [nome] LIKE '%' + @search + '%' AND @search <> ''
```

Comment: This still returns all rows when the search string is empty, which I think she is trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

This will return rows where the field nome is empty if the search string is empty.  If no rows have an empty [nome] then no rows are returned.

```
SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE [nome] Like Case When @search = '' Then '' Else '%' + @search + '%' end
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember to cast your column or parameter to nvarchar:

like this:

SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE [nome] LIKE '%' + CAST(@YourFieldOrParameter AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '%'